# What to do when you are sitting in a closed room without any fan or AC

Tags: thermodynamics

I suffered this today, when the solar panels of our college stopped to work.

Imagine a situation in which you are sitting in a botany lecture conducted by a 73 year old man, who cannot speak loud and hates the noise of running fans.

As I said earlier, solar panels stopped to work, so ACs were non-functional now and more over, my college is situated on the road side, and you might be knowing about the Indian traffic, population & noisy horn's of vehicles, so door was also closed, and all we have to do is just sit inside a room without any ventilation.

After this nearly whole class started making air for themselves with papers, after which the intensity of heat increased more, I think the reason for this was the heat generated by everyone's body while tilting papers before their faces.

So the question is:

What should one do in that situation, or what will make one most comfortable, sitting idle without any expenditure of energy (which generally cant happen :)) or start tilting the papers to overcome heat in the surroundings?

I have done both things, but both of them failed, so what should I actually do to minimise the heat intensity.

*I want an answer related to thermodynamical physics.*

Comment: Hmm, drink cold water?

Comment: @JoeBlow yeah i have tried it but, i think my question wasn't that clear, but, i was asking which would be better tilting a paper or sitting idol, because to move a paper form one place to other some work is to be done, which would lead to the generation of heat, but during most times i find many people, feeling comfort in tilting the bits of papers, why is it so ? because it would generate more heat, which should make body more warmer.... i just can't figure it out

Comment: You know, I believe the only reason air passing over you, actually feels cooling, has something to do with moisture / evaporation.  We need an expert!

Comment: i think you are correct

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this chapter [THE THERMODYNAMICS OF THE HUMAN BODY AND THE BIOPHYSICAL
FEATURES OF THE THERMAL ENERGY](http://www.biofizyka.sum.edu.pl/lab/lab5.prn.pdf)

In effect the main cooling method for the human body once the outside temperature gets larger than the body temperature is evaporation of sweat which is increased by fanning oneself with make do fans, as the humid air is pushed away and less saturated air is brought in contact with the body, thus increasing evaporation-cooling.

For a person fanning him/herself the advantage of the fan is obvious. Even in an auditorium full of people fanning themselves, until saturation humidity is reached the body will be cooler than without fanning. The temperature of the room will go higher by the extra kinetic energy but it does not affect the mechanics of cooling by evaporation  that is advantageous for the organism.

Answer (score 2):

Evaporative cooling mentioned by Anna is the way to go. You could consider making your clothes wet, that saves you from having to sweat. Every liter of water lost in the form of sweat requires you to drink 1.5 liters of water to rehydrate yourself, so you save water this way.